# Does $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$ imply $f(c)=0$ for some $a < c < b$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$ considering Riemann integral with no condition on $f$ not even continuity, does this implies that there exist some $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$. With continuity i am ok and can prove this using mean value theorem, Is this still true and what's the proof (if so)?

Comment: Though not an answer,with continuity u dont even need any theorem... :)
The only way a defenite integral can be 0 is when the area below x axis and area above x axis cancells out,for this to happen the graph has to meet x axis at some point.
Thus explained

Answer (score 11):

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & \text{if $x < 0$} \\ 1 & \text{if $x \ge 0$}\end{cases}$. Now calculate $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 f(x) \,\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 4):

No, if you cannot verify continuity, then you cannot verify Rolle's theorem. In other words, at the point where one might *expect* a zero, the function may be discontinuous.

Thus, if the function is discontinuous, there is no guarantee for any point equaling zero.

Comment: You correctly state that you cannot apply certain theorems, but what is really needed is an example such as $f:[-1,1]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
x&\text{if }x\ne0\\
1&\text{if }x=0
\end{array}\right.
$$